# What is the speed record for the Boeing 747 and Airbus A380?

Tags: boeing-747, airbus-a380

What are the speed records (true air speed) of these Jumbos: The Boeing 747-8 and the Airbus A380 if any?

Comment: indicated airspeed, true airspeed, mach number or groundspeed?

Comment: I dont think it is too broad. At most with 4 different speed you need just 8 numbers to come up with.

Comment: Probably during China Airlines flight 006's high speed dive

Comment: Tokyo -> Honolulu at 708 MPH (ground speed). https://goo.gl/6CVtvD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The published Maximum Operating Mach number (MMO) for the B747 is Mach 0.92 but it can sometimes be exceeded accidentally due to aircraft upset. It has been reported that Mach 0.99 was attained during a Boeing test flight in a slight nose down attitude.

The A380 has a slower MMO of Mach 0.89

The actual true airspeed of a Mach number will depend on the temperature and altitude but at 35,000 feet Mach 0.92 would be about 530 Knots. (610 mph)